# Predicting workplace performance of job applicants?

Tags: intelligence, performance, io-psychology, iq, big-five

As an employer who interviews engineering candidates, I'm interested in using the state of the art findings in psychometrics/psychology to predict which candidates are the most likely to be successful.

What I'm aware of is IQ and conscientiousness/industriousness are both very important and well evidenced.

Are there any other strong indicators that I can use in a practical way to filter candidates?

Comment: just to clarify, are you asking about all jobs or just engineering candidates. What's your primary focus?